# Get daily count of rows for a Time in sqlx

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, grpc, sqlx

My database table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE record 
(
    id         INT,
    status     INT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I want to know in last 1 day after 3 hours how many records are created.

For that I am using this query in postgres db  here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7a913

```
select gs.ts, count(r.created_at)
from generate_series(now() - interval '24 hour', now() - interval '3 hour', interval '3 hour') gs(ts) left join
     record r 
     on r.created_at >= gs.ts and
        r.created_at < gs.ts + interval '3 hour'
group by gs.ts
order by gs.ts;
```

And it's working fine and returning 8 records with 0 count in which hour no record made .

But when I am checking this using `SQLX` in golang grpc like this its returning only 1 hour record in which record is created only . and 7 interval in which not made are not showing .

my struct is

```
 type IssueCount struct {
        status            int 
        Count             int64
        Date              sql.NullTime `db:"due_date"`
    }
```

initializing response :

```
res := make([]*model.IssueCount, 0)
```

My query is

```
if err := tx.Select(&res, stmt, args...); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return res, nil
```

so what is way I can use using sqlx which can return me record created in last 24 hours with intervals of 3 hours and 0 count with interval in which record is not created .

Answer (score 0):

Finally got Answer I should Have get **ts** value in my struct as a response

```
type IssueCount struct {
        status            int 
        Count             int64
        Date              sql.NullTime `db:"due_date"`
        Ts                sql.NullTime 
    }
```

like this